# What will be the correct path of php file for http post request to get rid of 404 error in Angular?

Tags: php, angular

Its showing register_insert.php is not found. What should be the correct path? Please help. Here is my code

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
    insertData() {
          this.httpClient.post(
              "register_insert.php",
              {
                  'fullname':this.fullname, 
                  'email':this.email,
                  'role':this.role,
                  'typee':this.typee,
                  'password':this.password,

              }
          ).subscribe((data) => {
              alert("inserted");
              this.fullname = null;
              this.email = null;
              this.role = null;
              this.typee = null;
              this.password = null;
          });
      }
```

[This is the output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzpt3.png)

[image]

[This is the project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fuAv.png)

[image]

Comment: try: "silfraPoject/src/app/register/register_insert.php" but this is not best approach your using

Comment: same error --- 

POST http://localhost:4200/SilfraPoject/src/app/register/register_insert.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: sorry small typo: change SilfraPoject to SilfraProject

Comment: zone.js:3243 POST http://localhost:4200/SilfraProject/src/app/register/register_insert.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Sir, I have tried with these urls, but its showing same thing

Comment: I am using  two server simultaneously. ng serve and xampp. Both having different port number. This could be the reason?

Comment: thn try this  ->http://localhost/SilfraProject/src/app/register/register_insert.php

Comment: POST http://localhost:4200/localhost/SilfraProject/src/app/register/register_insert.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: here http:// is hidden in my previous comment, please add http:// before localhost

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/SilfraProject/src/app/register/register_insert.php' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Do I need to add headers into the script file?

Comment: add header('Content-type: application/json');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); in register_insert.php

Answer (score 0):

you should have host and serve your `register_insert.php` in a php server before calling the

```js
httpClient.post('http://yourlocalphpserver:xxxx/register_insert.php')
```

i notice that there is xampp path there. make sure xampp http server is started and host your php there and i believe default xampp port is localhost:80

if this is the case then just put full http url path

```js
httpClient.post('http://localhost/register_insert.php')
```

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/register_insert.php' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.